# Search function problem in Excel table using Excel Online for Business connector

Tags: excel, powerapps, powerapps-formula

What is the right syntax for searching an excel table connected with Excel Online for Business connector?

I've tried the following things:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try semicolon :, instead of comma this is due to your browser language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dutch, so I had to use the following syntax:

Search(HeyYouExtended; SearchBox.Text; "Name")

Comment: do you mind, I add my comment as answer and you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

try semicolon :, instead of comma this is due to your browser language.

Comment: Thanks! The language of the browser did the trick. Changing language in settings on office.com wasn't possible (you'd be redirected to organization)

Answer (score 0):

Addition to above answers,

Some separators and operators in Power apps formula will change based on the decimal separator of the author's language:

[image]

You have to use `;` as separator between parameters of a function and `;;` as separator between to functions.

**Documentation**: [Power Apps - Formula separators and chaining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/global#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator)